# Cross-compile from arm to x86

Tags: c, linux, cross-compiling

Is there a cross-compile tool like mingw-w64 that will compile code on a Linux ARM system for a Linux x86 system?

I have a BeagleBone Black that is running Debian wheezy that I would like to use to as a build server. It should just sit in the corner and each night build the code from certain repositories.

I have run some tests and found that I can get it to build the windows versions using mingw-w64. However, when I looked at what I thought would be the Linux build I noticed that it was building for ARM. I figure it should be possible to build the Linux versions, but I can't find a cross-compiler.

Comment: You may have to build your own cross toolchain - using an ARM system to build x86 binaries is an uncommon scenario.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case, but thought I should ask as final option.

Comment: You switch the role of PC and embedded system. ^_^

Comment: Yeah, but the embedded system is low power so it can sit there and chug away without me worrying about it.